# Error: NullPointerAccess: The variable " " can only be null at this location

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

I am creating a web service that queries my database and returns a list of the object in the database. I get the error: NullPointerAccess: The variable "varname" can only be null at this location. No matter where I put the variable, I get the same warnings. No matter what I put inside the variable, it returns null. Below is the method that it occurs in:

```
    public List<Contacts> getUsers()
  {     String test = null;
        String username = "root";
        String password = "ticket";
        String tablename = "users";
        String fieldname = "*";
        String query = "SELECT " + fieldname + " FROM " + "android." + tablename + ";";

        Contacts cont = new Contacts();
        List<Contacts> lstc = null;

        /* this chnk of code can appear more or less verbatim */
        /* in your database apps (including JSPs) */
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://"my IP address":3306/android";
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


        while (rs.next()){
            if (!(rs.getString("username") == null)){
             cont.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            }
            if (!(rs.getString("location") == null)){
             cont.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
            }
            if (!(rs.getString("updated_at") == null)){
             cont.setUpdated_at(rs.getDate("updated_at"));
            }
            if (!(rs.getString("idUsers") == null)){
             cont.setId(rs.getInt("idUsers"));
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            test = e.toString();
        }
         lstc.add(cont); //THIS IS THE VARIABLE THAT IS GIVING THE WARNINGS
        test = "blahbadslf";
        return lstc;
        }
```

The variable that is getting the warnings is my List lstc variable. When I try to add a  Object to the List I get the errors. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the Class just in case:

```
public class Contacts{
private int id;
private String username;
private String location;
private Date updated_at;

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setUpdated_at(Date updated_at) {
    this.updated_at = updated_at;
}
public Date getUpdated_at() {
    return updated_at;
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're getting that message because you have:

```
List<Contacts> lstc = null;
```

Did you mean:

```
List<Contacts> lstc = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
```

BTW:

You have a second bug:

```
    Contacts cont = new Contacts();  // you only create one of these
```

Better:

```
    while (rs.next()){
        Contacts cont = new Contacts();  // move to within the loop so one is created for every row in the result set
```

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out the second bug.. I had moved both variables upon getting the first warning and forgot to move that variable back. Also, I tried using: List<Contacts> lstc = new List<Contacts>(); That caused an error: cannot instantiate "List<Contacts". The "new ArrayList<Contacts>();" seems to be working but I will leave an update before selecting an answer. Thank you.

Comment: The method is still returning null.. Although, we did fix the current issue: does anyone know a quick and easy way that I can debug the web service method? I am new to web services and have no idea how to step through the code. Also: are my snippets
"if (!(rs.getString("location") == null)){
             cont.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
            }"
doing what I want them to do? I need to get the value that is in the column name.

Comment: @ninn - happy to help.  The method shouldn't be returning null anymore - you create the list unconditionally.  Do you mean its returning an empty list?  The best thing to do put a bunch of `Log` statements throughout the code to show what code is or isn't executing and to print the values of the different variables/expressions you're concerned about.   The examine LogCat for the messages to confirm what parts of the code are executing vs what's not and to see what the values of the variables are.

Comment: @Bert F - I am going to insert variables through the lines to see what lines are being executed as you said above. The return comes in as a SoapObject - and when I debug the method that calls the web service: I hover the SoapObject and it just tells me "return: null". Now, I don't know if that means that it is an empty list or just a null value in total. I've added a watch to the object, but I can't seem to figure out how to navigate through the contents of it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I that was my fault, I edited the code and forgot to return my static variable.

Comment: @Bert F - Now the console is outputting: [ERROR] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: wtp

When I "Googled" the error I found that it means it doesn't like the class Object I returned? Any ideas?

Comment: @ninn - sorry Axis is way out of my wheelhouse.  I did see this: http://wso2.org/forum/thread/3700: "Axis2 does not support operations with Java collections to be exposed as Web service operations. Please use arrays."  So the `List` is  the problem? Post another question to SO and get some help from with more info from me.

Answer (score 1):

There is this:

```
List<Contacts> lstc = null;
```

And then *no object is ever assigned* to `lstc`. Fail :(

Consider a `new ArrayList<Contacts>()` somewhere meaninful (such as in the declaration).

Comment: Epic Fail.. but, can you give me a code snippet on how I was supposed to do it.

Comment: @ninn I did :-) Remember that methods can only be invoked upon *objects* (and null is not an object) -- otherwise, NullPointerException, kaboom! Variables *store* objects. It's the responsibility of the code to ensure that variables contain the appropriate objects before they are used (if a variable doesn't contain an object, the only sensible option is generally a test in the form `null == variable`). As it is: `lstc.add(...)` attempts to invokes the `add` method on the *object stored in* the `lstc` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiated the list. The list is still null when you want to access it.

So you should use that:

```
List<Contacts> lstc = new List<Contacts>();
```

Comment: Well.. then, please explain to me better how exactly I am to instantiate of the List<Contacts>. I cannot use: List<Contacts> cont = new List<Contacts>; because it tells me that I cannot instantiate the "new List<Contacts>".

Comment: Instantiate, not "instanced".