# Null pointer access: The variable can only be null at this location

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stringbuffer

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<26;j++){
    if(str.charAt(i)== strChar.charAt(j) )
    * strSet1.append(str.charAt(i));
  }
    * strSet2.append(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at AterSeries.main(AterSeries.java:33)
```

why this code gives null pointer exception

warning: Null pointer access: The variable strSet1 can only be null at this location
Null pointer access: The variable strSet2 can only be null at this location

Comment: Please provide the entire warning message, and mark the line where it's occurring.

Comment: this means the length of your `str` string is less than either n or 26

Comment: I think your inner loop condition isn't right. what is your string length?

Comment: @TusharGupta: In that case it would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. `NPE` is thrown when you call a method on a null object for instance.

Comment: str is n which is input and strChar is 26 alphabates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are `strSet1` and `strSet2` initialized before this? If they are null, you'd get a `NullPointerException`.

*** EDIT ***

You cannot call `.append()` (or any other method) on a variable that is `null`. Initialize them as:

```
StringBuffer strSet1 = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer strSet2 = new StringBuffer();
```

Comment: initially Yes, all three variable are initialize with null, so what should i do? @tomppa

Comment: See updated answer, you cannot call methods on `null` objects.

Comment: latter str contains input and strChar is not null-it contains 26 alhabates @tomppa

Comment: What about `strSet1` and `strSet2`?

Comment: of course, str is less than 26 but str String is equal to n    @Tusar gupta

Comment: strSet1 and strSet2 is BufferString with null -- @tomppa

Comment: Thus you can fix the program by initializing them like shown above (edited answer again).